# Broken error popups when voting on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, session

I have observed twice that if

- I am using the mobile view (with Chrome for Android v18.0.something),
- my session has expired, but the page was loaded before it did (the time gap typically because I open-in-new tab several things to read, then don't read them all at once)
- and I click on a vote arrow,

then I will get an error popup with no error text, only "click to dismiss".

(If the page was loaded knowing I am not logged in (second point not holding), then I get a sensible "please login or register" popup, with an "×" button instead of "click to dismiss".)

Comment: This actually happens in the "main" site as well, not just the mobile version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an edge case where notification wasn't coming up with a message.

This has been fixed and should be available in the next build.